# Frequency of Words in Column of Strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a query that will allow me to

Imagine this is the table, "News_Articles", with two columns: "ID" & "Headline". How can I make a result from this showing

**NEWS_ARTICLES**

| ID | Headline |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | Today's News: Local Election Today! |
| 0002 | COVID-19 Rates Drop Today |
| 0003 | Today's the day to shop local |

1. One word per row (from the headline column)
2. A count of how many unique IDs it appears in
3. A count of how many total times the word appears in the whole dataset

**DESIRED RESULT**

| Word | Unique_Count | Total_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Today | 3 | 4 |
| Local | 2 | 2 |
| Election | 1 | 1 |

Ideally, we'd like to remove any conjunctions from the words as well (see "Today's" above is counted as "Today").

I'd also like to be able to remove filler words such as "the" or "a". Ideally this would be through some existing library but if not, I can always manually remove the ones I see with a where clause.

I would also change all characters to lowercase if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the headlines only in English?

Comment: Tag your version please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use full text search and `unnest` to extract the lexemes, then aggregate:

```
SELECT parts.lexeme AS word,
       count(*) AS unique_count,
       sum(cardinality(parts.positions)) AS total_count
FROM news_articles
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(to_tsvector('english', news_articles.headline)) AS parts
GROUP BY parts.lexeme;

 word  │ unique_count │ total_count 
═══════╪══════════════╪═════════════
 -19   │            1 │           1
 covid │            1 │           1
 day   │            1 │           1
 drop  │            1 │           1
 elect │            1 │           1
 local │            2 │           2
 news  │            1 │           1
 rate  │            1 │           1
 shop  │            1 │           1
 today │            3 │           4
(10 rows)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Do you know if there is a simple query for using this with sentiment analysis (even if it's just "positive" or "negative")?